# Making Div Disappear on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar that launches Teamspeak and Gary's Mod, but I want it to disappear on mobile devices. Can anyone help me out?

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav"  href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
    </ul>
</div
```

CSS

```
header.main_nav{
    padding: 1% 0;
    display: block;
}

.logo{
    margin: 3% auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo a{
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 2px 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.logo a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: use css `@media` queries

Comment: refer to: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using **bootstrap** you can use the class:

```
hidden-xs
```

or/and

```
hidden-sm
```

this class is basically a media query, a kind of conditional to run CSS. In this example the class `hidden-xs` will be `display: none` when the screen is smaller than 767px.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

[Bootstrap utilities classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Bootstrap has a lot of classes to help in this cases with a lot of width screens ready to use.

[MDN - Media Queries - CSS]

Comment: And if you look at the stoics of bootstrap you can see they use something called `media query` in CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: You can use a media-query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like this ?

```
<style>
        header.main_nav {
        padding: 1% 0;
        display: block;
    }

    .logo {
        margin: 3% auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .logo a {
        font-size: 3vw;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 2px 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .logo a:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000000;
    }

    @media ( max-width : 400px) {
        ul li.disappear a {
            display: none;
        }
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav disappear"><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak</a></li>
        <li class="nav disappear"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked for me when i tried it , can you show a picture of how you want the output to look like..